# How do I change a variable in a smartcontract (bool)

Tags: tokens

Say I have a published smart contract with a variable:

```
bool public myvariable = true;
```

Which is used in the contract later on by way of *if*'s which check whether `myvariable` is true or false.

How do I then change that variable, how do I communicate with the contract and what on earth do I tell it, in order to flip `myvariable` to `false`, say?

I suspect that this is a very basic question but the lack (absence?) of true beginners solidity information means I have to ask stupid questions. So far I've been using MEW to publish the contracts, and that has an "interact with contract" facility, offering me an ABI/JSON field to enter, presumably, the communication I wish to have with the contract?

Also, how do I stop just anyone triggering the same change?

Really not sure how to proceed from here. One idea I had was to code it so that the true/false state is flipped when a certain precise value of eth is sent to the contract, by my particular address. The precise amount of eth simply serving as a message of sorts. But I don't think that would "permanently" change the true/false, anyway.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a setter function in your contract.

something like

```
function set_myVariable(bool newVal) public{
    myVariable = newVal;
}
```

To prevent anyone from calling this, you need to use "require" in your function, to make sure msg.sender is the contract owner.

If you aren't already, I suggest using [Remix](https://remix.ethereum.org/) to play with, test and deploy your code.

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful. But then how do I go about triggering that function in the deployed smart contract? What code do I send to the contract in order to do that, and will the state change (from false to true, say) be "permanent", i.e. remain that way until I later flip it back, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

AnAllergy is correct. The only way to interact with a smart contract is through a function call. So you will need to write a setter function which allows your boolean variable to be changed based on the conditions you define.

Here is AnAllergy's code with the extra require statement. I would suggest adding a member variable of type **address** called `owner` to your contract. And set `owner = msg.sender` in your contract's constructor function.

```
function set_myVariable(bool newVal) public{
    require(msg.sender == owner);
    myVariable = newVal;
}
```

Comment: Thank you - that's very useful. But then how do I go about triggering that function in the deployed smart contract? What code do I send to the contract in order to do that, and will the state change (from false to true, say) be "permanent", i.e. remain that way until I later flip it back, perhaps?

Comment: You can interact w contracts via web3. Basically, connect to the node running the blockchain (local or remote) and then use the web3 library to write scripts that interact w the contract.