# How to interact with a smart contract to change a variable state

Tags: state-variable

[How do I change a variable in a smartcontract (bool)](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/42550/how-do-i-change-a-variable-in-a-smartcontract-bool/42599?noredirect=1#comment48313_42599)

As requested, a new followup question from the above^ about ethereum smart contracts (solidity)

If I have, early in the contract:

---

bool public myVariable = false;

---

and then later on:

---

function set_myVariable(bool newVal) public{
    require(msg.sender == *0x..myaddress*);
    myVariable = newVal;
}

---

How do I go about triggering that function in the published contract, and will it "permanently" toggle the true/false state of myVariable, despite the hard-coded =false part at the beginning?

Comment: This depends on what programming language you're using. If JavaScript, take a look at https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/13/building-decentralized-apps-with-ethereum-and-javascript/. I think it will help explain the basics.

Comment: Sorry - it's solidity, I should clarify. I was hoping to interact with the contract through something like MEW's "Interact with Contract" facility, rather than making an app to do it? I suspect I will just need a few lines of code and message them to the contract?

Comment: MEW should just work. Are you having trouble with it?

Comment: Well, I literally don't know what to type in, you see. Like, what do I write in order to achieve this - I don't know where to begin. See the final paragraph of my question, basically - really need introducing to how such things work.

Comment: Have you compiled and deployed your contract? If so, you should have an address and the ABI JSON. Put those things into MEW's "Interact with Contract" feature. If not, then start by learning how to compile and deploy contracts. https://programtheblockchain.com/posts/2017/12/19/testing-and-deploying-smart-contracts-with-remix/ might help.

Comment: Yes, I've compiled and deployed the contract(s) and they work as intended. My question is about how to interact with it once deployed. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: I believe I just said that: "If so, you should have an address and the ABI JSON. Put those things into MEW's 'Interact with Contract' feature."

Comment: smarx, I really appreciate your replies but I think we're misunderstanding here somewhat. I literally don't know what to type into the ABI/JSON input field, in order to change the bool state of the variable. I know that I use the MEW "interact with contract" page somehow or other, but I'm asking for detailed/beginner advice about what on Earth to actually type in there to achieve what I want. For example, I have the contract deployed, I have its address copied into the "interact with contract" page... now what?

Comment: You also need the contract's ABI. You get this when you compile the contract. If you're using Remix, the blog post I linked to describes where you get the ABI. You paste the entire ABI into that field.

Comment: OK, so I've got this from remix:
https://i.imgur.com/nqovSHs.png

Can you give me some hint at how I use this to achieve what I asked in the original question? I'm also happy to be referred to somewhere else that tells me what to do, if that is easier.

Comment: Click the clipboard icon to copy the ABI to your clipboard. Then paste it into the ABI field in MEW.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but then what? Perhaps to save yourself a lot of time, you could just quickly run through the answer to my question in the original post? I don't think we are getting anywhere, do you understand what I'm actually asking about? I want to change a variable between true and false, do you know how I can do that? Perhaps telling me all the steps in one answer would save this back-and-forth?

Comment: Once you've pasted in the address and the ABI, click the "Access" button. Then there will be a dropdown with the names of the functions. Choose the one you want to call: `set_myVariable`. Then a text box will appear where you can enter the value for the parameter `newVal`. I haven't tried that tool with a boolean before, so I don't know if you're expected to enter true/false or 1/0, but it should be one or the other. Then choose whatever way you access your wallet, and click the button labeled "WRITE" at the bottom. I hope those instructions are explicit enough.

Comment: Ah, I see - thank you, yes that's simpler than I expected. So I was able to deploy the contract with the variable hard-coded as false, and then as described ^ change it to true. But, not able to change it back once more. The second time I tried to, there were no options - just a fixed "True" and no facility to pick between them. I assume you can only change each variable once, perhaps? https://i.imgur.com/ttTIahm.png

Comment: What is `transferrable`? Are you sure you're picking the right function? (If you share the actual code you're using, I might be able to help more, but my guess is that you want to call something like `setTransferrable`.)

Comment: Sorry - "transferrable" is what "myVariable" is called in reality, forgot about that. Yes you're right, I didn't find the right part that time - I've just successfully flipped it from true-false-true-false. Marvelous, thanks for your help and sorry for being so slow to catch on.